# Pass URL path into $http get url- AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, api

I'm trying to get a value from a URL part, into my $http getURL request. I have tried a few solutions (such as HTML5mode) but have not had success.

Here is my code:

```
angular.module('myapp123.products', [])


.factory('productsApi', ['$http', '$location',
    function($http, $location){

        var BASE_URL = 'http://stashdapp-t51va1o0.cloudapp.net/api/item/';

        return {
            get: getApiData
        };

        function getData() {
            var product_id = $location.path().split("/")[3] || "Unknown"; //URL = /#/product/id/1234 <---
            return $http.get(BASE_URL + product_id);
        }
    }]
)

.controller('productsCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', 'productsApi', 'UserService',
    function($scope, $log, productsApi, UserService) {

        $scope.isVisible = function(name){
            return true;// return false to hide this artist's albums
        };

        // <======  Rewrite with accounts preferences
        productsApi.getApiData()
            .then(function (result) {
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(result.data)) //Shows log of API incoming
                $scope.products = result.data;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                $log.error(err);
            });
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your example has a lot of syntax errors in it. Here is what it should look like, based on what I think you are going for...

```
angular.module('myapp123.products', [])
    .config(locationConfig)
    .factory('productsApi', productsApiFactory)
;

locationConfig.$inject = ['$locationProvider'];
function locationConfig($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}

productsApiFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$location'];
function productsApiFactory($http, $location) {
    var BASE_URL = 'http://stashdapp-t51va1o0.cloudapp.net/api/list/';

    return {
        get: getData
    };

    function getData() {
        var product_id = $location.path().split("/")[3] || "Unknown";
        return $http.get(BASE_URL + product_id);
    }
}
```

In this version, the config function is correctly defined to set up `html5mode` and the service factory is configured to use `$location` each time the `get()` method is called.

You would use the service in a controller like this:

```
ExampleController.$inject = ['productsApi'];
function ExampleController(productsApi) {
    productsApi.get()
        .then(function onSuccess(res) {
            // handle successful API call
        })
        .catch(function onError(err) {
            // handle failed API call
        })
    ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks- do I need to do anything to my HTML markup (with Base)? I changed $locationProvider.html5Mode  to requireBase:false .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I haven't seen your html template and I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but this should answer your original question of how to pass the url path into an $http get request.

Comment: Thanks but your example seems to do something strange to all my url's- they all break. It seems to remove the /#/ from all my urls

Comment: That's html5mode. Remove the .config(locationConfig) line from my example, and the locationConfig function, if you don't want that to happen.